# pass date parameters from one SSRS report to another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image: parameters]

How can I pass these two date parameters to another report, so that users wont have to fill these boxes again?

Comment: Do you want to pass **from date** selection to **To date** selection ?

Comment: I want to pass  both: 'from' and to" date parameters to another report that has the same date parameters

Comment: is another report is subreport ?

Comment: no, its not a subreport

Comment: @Salta, edit this question to include more detail about how the 2 report are associated, how you are getting from one report to another, and any other details that may help us help you. There is so little here, it is just a guessing game right now.

Comment: Subreport? More Details? JFC - How do you down vote comments?

Comment: You can create another report using the same query in your multi-valued parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are linking one report from another, you can pass parameter in the ACTION of the text box.

In the **Use the Parameters** section, the name is the name of the parameter in the linked report. The value is what you want to populate the parameter with.

[image]

In my example, the **Department** parameter of the **Call Center Activity** report is populated with the same **Department** parameter in the current report.